# How to create one shapefile from multiple rasters?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Ok, I have about ten maps that connect along their edges to each other linking rivers and properties.  When I link them all in Inkscape I end up with a large file that won't save (and a smaller one with 5 of the properties saves but is too big and slow in QGIS).

So I am thinking that I will load them, about three linked together at a time, into QGIS and create my shapefiles.  Is it possible in QGIS to then merge/link the shapefiles along their edges so that the rivers and properties line up and create one large shapefile?   additionally, is it possible to then take this large shapefile and georeference it to a base map or can that only be done with rasters?

thanks

Comment: Which format are your input maps in? You should georeference the images before starting to digitize Shapefiles.

Comment: they are in png and tiff

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following work flow:

1. Georeference all images (QGIS Georeferncing tool). Make sure they align well after georeferencing.
2. Load one image at a time and digitize a Shapefile over it. When you are done with one image, load the next one and continue working on the SAME Shapefile.

Comment: thanks, sounds like a good idea.  If they don't match up perfectly after georeferencing can I move them manually (pan) until they match up and then set that location?

Comment: there has been talk about such a feature but I don't think it has been implemented yet